# How can I read a mapping of special characters from XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I am writing a program that converts data from a database into XML. The issue is that some of the values in the database have special characters. We have the typical XML special characters hardcoded in a map, but we would like to have a configurable XML mapping file that we will read at run time.

```
    <mapping source="ÿ" target="&#255;"/>
    <mapping source="þ" target="&#254;"/>
    <mapping source="ý" target="&#253;"/>
    <mapping source="ü" target="&#252;"/>
    <mapping source="û" target="&#251;"/>
    <mapping source="ú" target="&#250;"/>
```

We are using xstream to read the XML.

```
public class CharMapping {

    private static final String CHAR_MAPPING_FILE = "char_mapping.xml";
    private static final String XML_ROOT_ELEMENT = "mappings";

    private static String readXmlFile(String filename) {
        StringBuffer xmlContent = new StringBuffer();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename),"ISO-8859-1"))) {

            String currentLine;

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                xmlContent.append(currentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xmlContent.toString();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Map<String, String> getCharMapping() {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias(XML_ROOT_ELEMENT, java.util.Map.class);
        xstream.registerConverter(new XMLConfigConverter("source", "target", null, null));

        String xml = readXmlFile(CHAR_MAPPING_FILE);
        Map<String, String> relationsMapping = (Map<String, String>) xstream.fromXML(xml);
        return relationsMapping;
    }
}
```

```
public class XMLConfigConverter implements Converter {

    private String keyAttribute;
    private String valueAttribute;
    private String filterAttribute;
    private String filterValue;

    public XMLConfigConverter(String keyAttribute, String valueAttribute, String filterAttribute,
            String filterValue) {
        this.keyAttribute = keyAttribute;
        this.valueAttribute = valueAttribute;
        this.filterAttribute = filterAttribute;
        this.filterValue = filterValue;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object arg0, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            if (reader.getNodeName().equals("mapping")) {
                if (filterAttribute != null && filterValue != null) {
                    if (reader.getAttribute(filterAttribute).equals(filterValue)) {
                        putValueInMap(reader, map);
                    }
                } else {
                    putValueInMap(reader, map);
                }
            }
            reader.moveUp();
        }
        for(String charKey : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("mapping: " + charKey + " - " + map.get(charKey));       }
        return map;
    }

    private void putValueInMap(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, Map<String, String> map) {
        String key = reader.getAttribute(keyAttribute);
        String value = reader.getAttribute(valueAttribute);
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + " - Value: " + value);
        map.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Key: ?¿ - Value: ÿ
Key: ?? - Value: ?
Key: ?½ - Value: ?
Key: ?¼ - Value: ü
Key: ?» - Value: û
Key: ?º - Value: ú
```

I know this seems a bit weird to pull mappings for an XML FROM an XML. Idf this isn't possible is there any advice on a better solution? Would a CSV mapping be better?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Json

Comment: I have not, but that is a good idea

Comment: @DavidEnoma You might as well suggest they use C# instead of Java. Changing your technology because of a trivial user error is not a sensible way of approaching problem solving.

Comment: I was not suggesting Json, I asked is if he has. Suggesting Json would be me telling him directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is probably in the line

```
 new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename),"ISO-8859-1")))
```

where you are decoding the file using Java, rather than letting the XML parser do the decoding. From the evidence of your output, it appears the file is not encoded in iso-8859-1, but in utf-8, and if you had left the XML parser to do the decoding it would probably have got it right.

I don't actually know XStream, but the Javadoc says there is a version of the fromXML() method that accepts a `File` as input. I suggest you use that version of the method, which is likely to get the decoding right, and get rid of your `readXmlFile()` method, which appears to be getting it wrong.

It is possible, of course, that you will still have problems: perhaps the file is encoded in UTF-8 but declares its encoding as ISO-8859-1. But I think there's a good chance this change will fix it.

Comment: This got me a bit further! I now have a mapping from special character to special character. How would I keep the special character code, in the value attribute, from being evaluated?

Comment: You mean the "target" attribute? If you don't want the XML parser to interpret the character reference `&#255;` as a character reference, then don't use character reference syntax, use something else, e.g. `target="255"`

Comment: Aha! Wasn't thinking yesterday! So simple. Thanks!